# How do I get custom properties of a class with TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to retrieve custom properties of a class that inherits `ICustomTypeProvider`, that have custom properties created during run time similar to what is described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight_sdk/2011/04/26/binding-to-dynamic-properties-with-icustomtypeprovider-silverlight-5-beta/

If I use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myObject, false)` only the properties defined at design time are returned. How do I retrieve any custom properties that object may have if it impliments `ICustomTypeProvider`?

Edit: I also do not have a good way to test this since it requires that I have a custom type that fully implements `Type`.

Comment: myObject.GetType()..GetProperties()

Comment: That does not retrieve custom properties from objects implementing  `ICustomTypeProvider`

Comment: Implement `GetProperties()` in your base class.  Cast `myObject` to base type if needed: `(myObject as MyCustomTypeHelper).GetProperties()`.

Comment: In this case, I need to follow the interfaces structure as this is an operation that needs to work for any class that implements `ICustomTypeProvider`. I can't assume their class inherits from a `CustomTypeHelper`, since it might implement `ICustomTypeProvider` directly.